# Sending bolded words through Telegram

Tags: formatting, bots, telegram

I'm building a chatbot and I need to send some words in bold. According to the Telegram documentation, to make a word bold, you need to put two asterisks at the beginning of it and two at the end. However, it doesn't work:

[image: Bot on telegram]

So I was wondering if anyone knows if anything has changed and if the documentation is out of date

I tried with two asterisks and with HTML tags

Comment: Did you set the parse_mode to markdown? Otherwise the `*` won't work. Please share your code.

Comment: I'm using a low-code platform to send the messages

Comment: Please share the code, you're probably missing parse mode.